# Google Genomics API

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-genomics

Trying to use Google Genomics, following instructions found here: https://developers.google.com/genomics/

Trying to set up OAuth Client id (Section 4: Authenticate), from the GoogleCloud console, step c tells me: "On the APIs & auth tab, select APIs and make sure Genomics API is set to ON"

... but I can't find Genomics API in the list.  How do I "add" Genomics API to the list?  (I have been approved for the Google Genomics Preview).

Comment: Did you apply for access and have that application accepted?  Access to the Genomics API is currently available to whitelisted users only.
To request access, please fill out this simple form to tell us about yourself and your research interests, and we will let you know when we're ready to work with more partners.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I received the approval email 7 days ago and it says "Your email address will be added to the whitelist group shortly". But I still can't find Genomics API in the list, just like op.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII, I am also on the whitelisted group -- got an email on April 14th.  But I still can't access the Genomics API.

Comment: Sounds like the right path! You may have to get in touch with Google if there are still problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but anyway.

The best way to communicate with Genomics API developers is the [issue tracker](https://github.com/googlegenomics/genomics-tools/issues)

To stay on topic, I just received an invitation to join genomics-api-tt group, and once I accepted the invitation, Genomics API became visible on API & Auth / APIs page in my Google Cloud project.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that the email address that was added to the whitelist (the one that is in [this group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/genomics-api-tt)) is the same address that is logged into the Developer's Console when you try to turn the API on.

If you accidentally asked for access on a non-google account just request access again and that new email will be added.

(And if you have more than one google account, just double check your current login)